# Robotframework / selenium - panning with mouse

Tags: selenium, drag-and-drop, mouseevent, robotframework, pan

In the SeleniumLibrary documenation, there are explanations of the keywords for Drag And Drop, Drag And Drop By Offset -

I'd like to pan using mouse - click mouse down, move and click mouse up, without using the locator. Is there any existing keyword for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using "Mouse Down" at one location, and then "Mouse Up" at another location.  You'll need to use some locators for this, but not necessarily the specific one you want to drag and drop with.

See here:  http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Mouse%20Down